# Looking for a workstation motherboard for anything up to £700

Tags: motherboard, performance

**Backstory:** The last time I bought a motherboard was about 13 years ago, and it did great. It was a ROG Maximus II Formula, which I overclocked a quad-core water-cooled CPU in. Yes 4 CORES!! Well, it was impressive at the time. I just checked, and they're selling for £200 on eBay!(What?) Anyway, it's getting a bit old and temperamental, so I've been mostly using my laptop for over a year. I've now decided to revamp the beast, but I'm overwhelmed by similar products. I want a motherboard to stand out and excite me, but none have. Maybe because important numbers have changed slightly, so they make less sense to me now. The main thing that drew me to the Maximus II was the 1600 MHz FSB speed.

**Usage:** I mainly design sounds with my processor-intensive custom synth and create large music productions across 24 or more tracks, with a lot of Virtual Studio Tech; samplers, synths and interwoven effects. But I also do some video editing and effects (AE/PP) and content creation on the side (as well as some programming (VS). I suppose I'm a bit of a renaissance man!).

**Wants:**

- POWER! I would like "power" to spare.
- Intel Chipset (z690?)- I'm thinking a 12th or 13th gen 16-core i9 (socket 1700) (I haven't had good experiences with AMD, but would consider it, if it's got good reviews, etc)
- DDR4/DDR5 compatibility
- fast and abundant storage potential
- As much RAM slots and capability as possible
- I don't mind buying a gaming MB as I did before as they tend to be very customizable, but big names cost money in this game!
- I don't really want any novelty, faddy, unneeded superficial features like graphic displays, etc. It will just go unused and probably degrade, like my LCD voltage/temperature display of my Maximus II formula. Saying that, it's *not* a game stopper. But I'm not tryna impress anyone with the look.

**Needs:**

- a PCIe slot for my audio interface. It's in [the very bottom one](https://www.motherboarddb.com/motherboards/528/ROG%20Maximus%20II%20Formula/), now.
- at least one x16 for graphics card
- Robust overclocking (I like to fiddle)
- ATX or EATX form factor (I have an Antec 1200 case, but I'll mangle it to fit an EATX if I have to)

**Price:**
Anything up to 700 GBP. It could be £260... I do like to save if I can, but good, robust and powerful core features are worth the extra coin to me. If I get a cheaper MB (~£300), I may get a better model i9 CPU, as both can amount to about a grand (£1,000) *if it's worth it*. The LAST THING I want is to set it all up to find there's a bottlenecking issue or something.

I don't care if it has WiFi or not, I'd just plug a cable in if it doesn't. (I like cables)

Hopefully I can get some recommendations that spark my interest.